# Youtube Data API 403 forbidden after numerous successful thumbnails.set() calls

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

```
def update_thumbnail_on_youtube(video, path):
    try:            
        request = youtube.thumbnails().set(videoId=video['id'], alt="media", media_body=MediaFileUpload(path))
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        raise(e)
    finally:
        os.remove(path)
```

this works fine. i'll give a list of videos from my own youtube playlist, auth, and path is a local image file. after a hundred if these updates it'll throw 403

typically wait a day and it fixes? maybe? doesnt say what the deal is in the documentation.

403 is as follows

```
b'{\n "error": {\n "code": 403,\n "message": "The caller does not have permission",\n "errors": [\n {\n "message": "The caller does not have permission",\n "domain": "global",\n "reason": "forbidden"\n }\n ],\n "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"\n }\n}\n'
```

edit: it does start working after around 24 hours. guys at youtube/google, bros, just let me know i'm being limited instead of having me pull my f8ckin hair out. imagine a world...

Comment: please edit the question and include the full error message not just the error code.

Comment: Obviously, YouTube is limiting your traffic.

Comment: Just trying to update my own thumbnails quick and efficiently. Though that's what the API was for.